# How do I type a path of a file if a folder has spaces in its' name and I can't/don't want to change it's name?

Tags: cmder

I'm using cmder as my command line and if I want to access folders inside a given one i'm already in, e.g. doing `cd [foldername]`, I don't know how to access folders that have spaces in them because then cmder only processes the first word in the folder name instead of the full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
cd "folder with space"
```

And you can also press tab before typing name and cmd will help you out.

Comment: What if I want to use it in VSCode and have like C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Documents\ what can i do for the space in My Documents?